# mysql insert information from multiple rows from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using **MySQL version 5.6**.
I have a table `event` that takes two ids and a date, and a table `student` that contains a column `id`. I want to insert two ids when the name match `(WHERE firstname =.., AND lastname=..,)`. However, I don't quite know how to take `id` from two rows in one insert command. Can any one help me please?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are trying to insert into a table, then you want to use `insert`.  To get data from another table or query, you would want the `insert . . . select` form.

From what you say, this seems something like what you want:

```
insert into event(id1, id2, date)
    select s1.id, s2.id, now()
    from student s1 cross join
         student s2
    where s1.id <> s2.id and
          s1.firstname = firstname and s1.lastname = lastname and
          s2.firstname = firstname and s2.lastname = lastname;
```

It would return all pairs of students where the names match (but don't have the same id).

Comment: This is not quite what I asked for, probably due to my ambiguous question. But I worked from it and got what I wanted. So thank you very much!

Comment: One more question: I noticed that if I had duplicates in my table it would cross count each one multiple times and the result will be, if 8 duplicates for example, 64 rows. I guess this is because of the "cross join" or something not set in where clause. Is there a way to not select the ones that I have selected in previous rows in a query?